# Difference between Chinese and English text wrapping when showing text in Vue project

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

When I use many English words it will show like:

[image: English]

When I use many Chinese words it will show like:

[image: Chinese]

If you can tell me the reason why English text does not wrap but Chinese text does, I will be very appreciative!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example, it looks like you had many English letters, rather than words. If you had spaces between the English letters then I suspect that wrapping would occur. With Chinese the distinction between letters and words blurs and so you're allowed to wrap between each glyph.

Perhaps look at CSS `overflow-wrap: break-word;` or `word-break: break-all;`  for wrapping long English words:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_text/Wrapping_breaking_text